# jQuery select users doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was planning to have a select input type where in when I select a user 
it will only show the tweets from those users.

What I did is I created the ff html:

```
    <select id="selectUser">
        <option value="all">All</option>
        <option value="user1">user1</option>
        <option value="user2">user2</option>
        <option value="user3">user3</option>
        <option value="user4">user4</option>
        <option value="user5">user5</option>
    </select>
```

And then I created a function that will handle the work:

```
Tweets.displayUserTweets = function(id) {
     $('#main-content').html('');
     var streamLength = streams.users[id].length;
     var index = 0;
     while (index < streamLength) {
         var tweet = streams.users[id][index];
         var dayWrapper = moment(tweet.created_at).fromNow();
         $('#main-content').append('<div class="box-content"><img src="img/' + tweet.user + '.png" align="left" class="avatar-main"><h5 class="fullNameMain">' + tweet.user + '<span class="userNameMain"> @' + tweet.user + ' * ' + dayWrapper + '</span></h5><p class="tweetContent">' + tweet.message + '</p><ul><li><span class="comment"></span>48K</li><li><span class="retweet"></span> 50K</li><li><span class="heart"></span>100K</li><li><span class="msg"></span>22K</li></ul></div>');
         index++;
     }
 };
```

And then whenever the document is ready and the user select one of these users it will empty the main-content box then show the users tweets only.

```
 $('#selectUser').on('click', 'button', function() {
         if (this.value === 'all') {
             Tweets.latestTweets();
         } else {
            Tweets.displayUserTweets(this.value);
         }
     });
```

Right now it's not working. Any idea what should I tweak?

Answer (score 0):

Change event handler `click` to `change` and it will work.

The click handler will fire though when set, but will not listen to the changes made, since clicking only opens the menu and happens before any changes where made. `change` fires after a user made a change to the list.

```
$('#selectUser').on('change', function() {
     if (this.value === 'all') {
         Tweets.latestTweets();
     } else {
        Tweets.displayUserTweets(this.value);
     }
 });
```

Comment: the idea is right but it doesnt work on my codes. Mind helping me out?

Comment: Are there any errors in the console (hit F12) or other indications what the code is doing?

Comment: No errors at all. if you want we can move this to the chat so you can see.

Comment: Would you like to help me on this?

Comment: Would like to, but no time at this moment.